# Particle paths - the distance moved by a particle in a velocity field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, differentiation, flow, calculus

This question is is context to particle paths.

Particle paths are trajectories of a given particle in the velocity field:

$$\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{x},t)$$

A particle location at position $\boldsymbol{x}$ at time $t$ moves a distance:

$$\delta\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{x},t)\delta t+O(\delta t^2)\qquad\text{in a time }\delta t$$

I dont understand where the second terms on the right hand side of the equation comes from. I though the first term is enough as it gives an exact answer, since $d=vt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic result from calculus. The derivative of a function $f(t)$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\frac{df(t)}{dt}=f'(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}

Now you can Taylor expand:

\begin{equation}
f(t+\Delta t)=f(t)+f'(t)\Delta t +O(\Delta t^2)
\end{equation}

It means

\begin{equation}
\frac{df(t)}{dt}=f'(t)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{f'(t)\Delta t +O(\Delta t^2)}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}

If we write
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\Delta t=dt
\end{equation}

then we have

\begin{equation}
df=f'(t)dt+O(dt^2)
\end{equation}

Comment: I understand your answer but would you point out why the following argument is incorrect:   Since distance = velocity times time, we have: the change in distance = velocity times change in time $$\delta\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{x},t)\delta t$$

Comment: That formula works only if the motion occurs with constant speed. For example, if there is acceleration, than the distance grows quadratically with time, i.e $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$. The general formula for distance is $x=\int v\, dt$

Comment: Anyway, since $dt$ is infinitesimal, then you can drop $dt^2$ in the formula, since it is an infinitesimal of higher order.